# Does Firestore auth on GAE need more than one service?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm interested in using Firestore to authenticate users to my Flask web app, and I am following [this demo provided by Google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine).

In the demo code, there is a backend service that handles AJAX requests and a frontend service that presents a single page app (one each of an html, js, and css).

It seems pointless to break this code up into two services when one service should be able to handle it just fine.

Am I missing some aspect of this that requires two services? I just don't understand why Google would needlessly complicate the demo by using two services...

Comment: As an architectural pattern, the separation of concerns (front-end / back-end) is a very valid use case.  Perhaps it's overkill for your demo / toy problem, but I'm gonna guess they're trying to reinforce accepted design patterns as well.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose, but it really hinders understanding for those of us who don't use the single-page-app pattern.  If you are confident that the answer to my question is "no" then feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, not required.  Just a really good idea to get used to.  See also [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) as an architectural pattern for a very robust argument.

Comment: It may be a good idea for a single-page app, but it isn't practical for more general websites.  There are a lot of ways to achieve "separation of concerns" even if you use only a single GAE service.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is NO, you don’t need more than one service to have implemented your back-front end. As mentioned by Paul the sample is using the separation of concern as a good practice.

Finally the sample is also a good guide to implement the pieces of code that are relevant for you, and the whole sample will let you have a running environment that you can use to perform local tests in order to better understand the functionalities.